# Can someone help me modify this Excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro spreadsheet that I'm trying to edit. This is a cleaner that cleans fields in certain columns used to process data. The code was written by a previous co-worker. The file can be found here.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/luv3wsfhdvz20h7/Master_data_scrubber_-_USE_THIS_ONE.xlsm

Anways I'm relatively new to excel and I don't know much about VBA so when looking over the code i didn't understand much of it all. I'm trying to get edit the cleaning macro. There is a clean all button which Will take Columns A-AP and create a new column next to it with the cleaned values. Each column also has individual button cleaners.

Column B contains a sku number column (I.G 40118) and the clean button will add the manufacturer code to it (i.g. happ). Thus after pressing Clean, a column will be inserted in between B and C. In this new column will be the value happ40118.

Column K is labeled Image name. So the value in for say K2 could be "hungryhippos-box.jpg" Currently the clean button for Column K just copies the value an pastes it in a cell from the new inserted column.

I want the button to actually instead of copying the value take the values from the cells in the Cleaned_Sku Column (the newly created column C) and then tack on the extension from the value of Column K (.jpg) and concatenate them together in the newly created Column L. So the value will look like happ40118.jpg.

Here is what what the code looks like below.

```
**For the Clean All**

Private Sub Clean_ALL_Click()

MsgBox ("This action will take a few moments.")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Cells.Select
    Range("AM9").Activate
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 8
    End With

Call CleanSKUs_Click
Call CleanBrand_Click
Call Clean_MFG_SKU_Click
Call Clean_UPC_Click
Call Clean_ISBN_Click
Call Clean_EAN_Click
Call Clean_product_name_Click
Call Clean_Short_desc_Click
Call Celan_long_desc_Click
Call Clean_Image_Click
Call Clean_MSRP_Click
Call Clean_Cost_Click
Call Clean_product_weight_Click
Call Clean_product_weight_u_Click
Call Clean_product_length_Click
Call Clean_product_width_Click
Call Clean_product_height_Click
Call Clean_product_lwh_uom_Click
Call Clean_age_range_Click
Call Clean_Origin_Click
Call Clean_origin_text_Click
Call Clean_Product_safety_Click
Call Clean_category_Click
Call Clean_Processed_date_Click
Call Clean_Interactive_URL_Click
Call Cleaned_Drop_ship_Click
Call Cleaned_Developmental_Attributes_Click
Call Clean_keywords_Click
Call Clean_product_available_date_Click
Call Clean_gender_Click
Call Clean_attribute_Click
Call Clean_products_Awards_Click
Call Clean_P_Awards_index_Click
Call Clean_Out_of_Production_Click
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ("The data cleaning is done!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "  All the data has been copied to a new column," & vbCrLf & "check the data before using it.")

End Sub

----------
**For the Clean SKU** 

Private Sub CleanSKUs_Click()

 Dim a$, b$, C$, prefix$, count$, MyLetter$, number, ii, j, I As Integer
 Dim lr As Long
 Dim r As Range
 Dim popbox As String
 Dim popcount, loopI As Integer

 For intCounter = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count
    count$ = Cells(1, intCounter).Address(False, False)
    Range(count$).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "SKU" Then
      number = intCounter
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Cleaned SKUs"
    Exit For
    End If
 Next intCounter

ii = number / 26
 If ii > 1 Then
   ii = Int(ii)
   j = ii * 26
   If number = j Then
     number = 26
     ii = ii - 1
   Else
     number = number - j
   End If
   MyLetter = ChrW(ii + 64)
 End If

 MyLetter$ = MyLetter$ & ChrW(number + 64)
 lr = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'find Last row

 Set r = Range(MyLetter$ & "2:" & MyLetter$ & lr) 'define working range

 Sheets("VARs").Activate
 ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Select
 prefix$ = Selection.Value
 Sheets("NewData").Activate

 Dim d
 Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 popcount = 0
 loopI = 1

 For Each cell In r

 loopI = loopI + 1
 If d.Exists(cell.Value) Then
    ' tag the d(cell.value) row   -- i.e. (the first appearance of this SKU)
    Rows(d(cell.Value) & ":" & d(cell.Value)).Select
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    ' tag the row
    Rows(loopI & ":" & loopI).Select
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    ' add duplicate to popup box
    popcount = popcount + 1
 Else
    d.Add cell.Value, loopI
 End If

 a$ = cell.Value
 For I = 1 To Len(a$)
 b$ = Mid(a$, I, 1)
 If b$ Like "[A-Z,a-z,0-9]" Then
 C$ = C$ & b$
 End If
 Next I
 C$ = prefix$ & C$
 cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = LCase(C$) 'set value
 C$ = "" 'reset c$ to nothing
 Next cell

 If popcount > 0 Then
 MsgBox ("There were " & popcount & " repeated SKUs.")
 End If

End Sub

----------
***For the Clean Image(This is the one I want to modify)**

Private Sub Clean_Image_Click()

 Dim a$, b$, C$, count$, MyLetter$, number, ii, j, I As Integer
 Dim lr As Long
 Dim r As Range

 For intCounter = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count
    count$ = Cells(1, intCounter).Address(False, False)
    Range(count$).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Image filename" Then
      number = intCounter
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Cleaned Image Filename"
    Exit For
    End If
 Next

ii = number / 26
 If ii > 1 Then
   ii = Int(ii)
   j = ii * 26
   If number = j Then
     number = 26
     ii = ii - 1
   Else
     number = number - j
   End If
   MyLetter = ChrW(ii + 64)
 End If

 MyLetter$ = MyLetter$ & ChrW(number + 64)
 lr = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'find Last row
 Set r = Range(MyLetter$ & "2:" & MyLetter$ & lr) 'define working range

 For Each cell In r
 a$ = cell.Value
 a$ = Trim(a$)
 cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = a$ 'set value
 a$ = "" 'reset c$ to nothing
 Next cell

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: OK, first things first.  Most people will chastise you and tell you that SO is not a code writing service.  While you are presenting code with a problem, you're not saying what you've done to try to achieve it.  Meanwhile, I kind of enjoy this kind of task, so see below.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Clean_Image routine requires that the Clean_SKU routine has already run.  They're in the right order in the Clean_all routine, but since they can be run separately, I've added some code to make sure that clean image doesn't try to run unless clean sku has already done so.

Add this in between the first intCounter loop and the line "ii= number"  Note that I said after the first intCounter loop.  There will be two loops when you're done, one to find the Image File Name" column, and then the new one to get the cleaned SKU Column.

```
'This section will find the column that the new Cleaned SKU value is in.  If it's not there, the procedure aborts.
 For intCounter = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count
    count$ = Cells(1, intCounter).Address(False, False)
    Range(count$).Select
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Cleaned SKU" Then
      SKUColumn = intCounter
      Exit For
    End If

    If SKUColumn = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You must run the Clean SKUs program first.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
 Next intCounter
```

Now, you need to find the image extension, and the sku to create the new image file name.  I've added some variables that are a little bit easier to read than a$, b$ etc (oh yeah, Dim Statements...)  Change the top part to this:

```
 Dim a$, b$, c$, SKUValue$, ImageExtension$, count$, MyLetter$, number, ii, j, I As Integer
 Dim lr As Long, SKUColumn As Long, ImageRow As Long
 Dim r As Range, cl As Range
```

we'll talk more about DIM statements later.

```
'I didn't analyze this or try to change it, but I think it's a bit odd
 MyLetter$ = MyLetter$ & ChrW(number + 64)
 lr = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'find Last row
 Set r = Range(MyLetter$ & "2:" & MyLetter$ & lr) 'define working range

 'I changed 'cell' to 'cl' because cell is a reserved word, but in this instance is being used as a variable
 'and that's confusing
 For Each cl In r
  'take the file extension from the file name (maybe it's always .jpg, and maybe it isn't.
    ImageExtension = Right(cl.Value, 4)
    'get the row number we're on
    ImageRow = cl.Row
    'and get the SKU value from the Cleaned SKU column
    SKUValue$ = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(ImageRow, SKUColumn)) 'get the cleaned SKU
    'put them together in the new column
    cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = SKUValue & ImageExtension
  Next cl
```

and that should work.

Now, about DIM statements.  They don't actually work as you think they do.
the a$, b$, c$ part does create string variables, because of the '$', but 'number' ii, and j are not numbers, they're variants.  Each variable has to be given it's date type explicitly, or they default to variant.  Only I is an integer.

OK, so try these changes, and if you have any problems, or have questions, post a comment.

Comment: So does this mean I'd have to modify the DIM statements on the whole sheet 3(NewData) page for everything to work correctly? In this chat I only pasted partial code. It isn't the whole code line, hence why i sent a link.

Comment: I'll have to look at it again, but in general, wherever you have a statement such as "DIM A, B, C as string", only C is a string.  A and B are variants.  Sometimes that can cause unexpected behaviour.  I try to dimension all variables as explicitly as possible.  It's just a matter of adding "as string (or whatever variable type you need) in lines where multiple variables are dimensioned.  You should probably have "Option Explicit" at the top, to ensure all variables used are properly dimensioned.